# Propagated pipes in .NET?

Tags: .net, messaging

I'm looking to implement an inter-process messaging solution for a suite of .NET applications that can send a message to every running instance of an app from our toolchain on a single machine. Our messaging requirements were nicely met in the past by using named pipes, and I'm curious as to whether I can adapt our existing infrastructure to send multicast messages. Do .NET pipes support such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

.Net can utilize named pipes in the same way native programs can.  Check out the `System.IO.Pipes` namespace.  In particular the `NamedPipeClientStream` and `NamedPipeServerStream` class.  These are just wrappers over the native version of named pipes so it will function in the way you are expecting.

Comment: That sounds quite promising -- my existing messaging implementation takes exactly that approach. I take it that named pipes have multicast capability, then?

Comment: @estanford I *believe* they support multicast but I'm not experienced enough with them to say for 100% sure that they do

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF for Multicast Messaging. Here is an [example walk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh705316) through.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Messaging Queue (MSMQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sound like exactly what you want to do.

Comment: That was my first choice as well, but some of the customers who use the app are on XP machines and don't plan on moving anytime soon. MSMQ has a thorny relationship with XP, and also requires that we enable certain OS features that require admin privileges to set, which the users don't necessarily have.

Comment: Ok was not aware of the XP issue but shouldn't you be able to get the Admin to install the software initially and just have them run it?